# Programming challenge while loops and for loops

Tags: python

I have been asked to make a piece of code including a for loop and a while loop. I was asked to:

- Get the user to input a number
- Output the times table for that number
- Starts again every time it finishes

I was able to do the for loop like so:

```
num= int(input ("Please enter a number."))
for x in range (1,13):
    print (num,"x",x,"=",num*x)
```

But I cannot figure out how to make it repeat, any ideas?

Comment: Have you heard of a *while* loop?

Comment: Yes it is used in situation where the number of iterations is unknown. It will execute a block as long as a given condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your code inside a while loop.

```
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    for x in range(1,13):
        print("{} x {} = {}".format(num, x, num*x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be nice for you to handle errors. 
If a user decides to enter a non digit character it will throw an error.

```
while True:
    num = input('please enter a number')
    if num ==0:
        break
    elif not num.isdigit():
        print('please enter a digit')
    else:
        for x in range(1, 13):
            mult = int(num)
            print('%d x %d = %d' %(mult, x, mult*x))
```